# Can the word "Sign" be applied to digital displays?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

It has previously been my understanding that the word "Sign" mostly refers to printed media. Such as posters and metallic traffic signs. Performing a google image search on the word also seems to indicate that this is the case.

However, I have recently run into occurrences where the word was used for digital displays. For example, displays which show real time traffic information (buses, trains, etc). Is this also a correct usage of the word, or would "Display" be more appropriate?

Comment: Did you try to confirm your understanding with any dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

A sign does not have to be exclusively printed or painted.

> a display (such as a lettered board or a configuration of neon
> tubing) used to identify or advertise a place of business or a product

[Sign (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sign)

Neon signs have been used for around 100 years, and now we also have modern types.

[image]

[image]